# Why do excited states of charge qubits have higher charge sensitivity than the ground state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, josephson-junction

Lets define charge qubits as two coupled superconductors connected by a Josephson tunnel junction governed by the Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
H = 4 E_C \left(n - n_g\right)^2 - E_J \cos{\phi}
\end{equation}
where $E_C$ is the charging energy, $E_J$ the Josephson energy, $n$ the number of Cooper pairs that traverse the junction, $\phi$ the phase difference across the junction, and $n_g$ a continuous offset charge.

This Hamiltonian has been thoroughly studied in Cooper pair boxes and transmons, among others. One finds that the energy levels look like in the paper by [Koch](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0703002):
[image]

What I'd like to emphasize in this picture (harder to see in panel 4) is that the excited states always have a stronger dependence on $n_g$ than the ground state. They have more 'charge dispersion', and are more charge sensitive.

But why is this the case? Why do the higher lying states have a higher degree of charge sensitivity? I imagine it has something to do with the wavefunctions/eigenstates being broad in a certain basis, but also for that I'd like to gain some intuition. Or is it as simple as that the states live higher in potential well defined by the cosine, and thus see a smaller barrier when tunneling from $\phi = 0$ to $\phi = 2\pi$? The smaller that barrier, the less well-defined phase is, and the more narrow you are in the charge basis. Which means small changes in charge influence you more? This is mainly me trying to argue why this happens to myself, I'd be happy to hear from someone more knowledgeable however.

Comment: I am happy to answer this question if you are still interested, but how well do you understand the plot shown in part (a)? To be more specific: (i) do you understand why there are gaps $\sim E_J$? and (ii) do you understand why the gaps occur at the values of $n_g$ that they do? The reason I ask is that I think it helps to approach this problem from the limit of charge qubit.

Comment: I'm still interested for sure, that'd be very helpful. In terms of what I understand about the plot, the avoided crossings happen at these specific values of $n_g$ because this is where for one charge state with $N$ Cooper pairs an additional $0.5 n_g = 1e$ of charge is induced, while for the next charge state with $N+1$ cooper pairs this is $-1e$, making their energies degenerate. In the presence of $E_J \cos \phi$ these crossings become avoided crossings as the Josephson term couples the two charge states, with $~E_J$ the energy cost of moving a Cooper pair across the junction.

Comment: Very well. I basically want to argue that in the charge qubit limit, the enhanced charge dispersion of higher excited states has to do with how $d/dn_g \{4E_c(n-n_g)^2\}$ grows with respect to the values of $n$ that define the different energy levels. This argument also relies on the fact that the gap size shrinks for higher excited states, as the relative strength of the $E_J \cos \phi$ potential decreases (think of the charge qubit as a free particle in the presence of a small nonbinding potential).

Comment: That makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it helps to analyze this problem in the following two limits: (i) when $E_C \gg E_J$ (the charge qubit limit) and (ii) when $E_J \gg E_C$ (the transmon limit). Since the charge qubit came first, let's begin our analysis there.

If $E_J \rightarrow 0$, the eigenergies are given by
$$E_n = 4E_C (n-n_g)^2,$$
where $n$ is the integer number of cooper pairs on the capacitor plate. Note that the energy basis is the (cooper pair) number basis. In other words, the $n^{th}$ excited corresponds to a state with $n$ cooper pairs on the island. By plotting this expression for $E_n$ versus $n_g$ for $n \in \{\ldots,~-2,~-1,~0,~+1,~+2, \ldots \}$, one obtains Fig. (a) from the Koch paper (apart from the small splittings $\sim E_J$) as depicted below:
[image]

But where do the splittings in Fig. (a) come from and why does the magnitude of the splitting appear to decrease as $n$ grows? Let's confine ourselves to the $01$-subspace with $E_J\neq0$ and compute the charge dispersion of the ground state. We find that our Hamiltonian is given by
$$
H_{01}(n_g) = \begin{pmatrix}
4E_c(0-n_g)^2 & -E_J/2\\
-E_J/2 & 4 E_C(1-n_g)^2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
At $n_g=0.5$, the diagonal entries of this matrix are equal, in other words
$$H_{01}(n_g=0.5) = -\frac{E_J}{2}\hat{\sigma}_x + E_c \times \hat{1}.$$
The eigenstates and eigenenergies of this matrix are given by:
$$|1_q\rangle = (|0\rangle - |1\rangle)/\sqrt{2} \leftrightarrow +E_J/2 + E_C$$
and
$$|0_q\rangle = (|0\rangle + |1\rangle)/\sqrt{2} \leftrightarrow -E_J/2 + E_C.$$
At $n_g=0$, we find that
$$
H_{01}(n_g = 0) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -E_J/2\\
-E_J/2 & 4 E_C
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which has eigenstates and eigenenergies given by:
$$|1_q\rangle \simeq |1\rangle \leftrightarrow  4E_C - \frac{E_J^2}{16 E_C}$$
and
$$|0_q\rangle \simeq |0\rangle \leftrightarrow  \frac{E_J^2}{16 E_C}.$$ Note that we have ignored the effect of the off-diagonal coupling on the eigenstates, but we have included the energy level shifts as they will be useful later. Putting this all together, the ground state charge dispersion
$$
\epsilon_0 = |E_0(n_g=0.5)-E_0(n_g=0)| = E_C - E_J/2 \approx E_C.
$$
Graphically, $\epsilon_0$ roughly corresponds to the energy at which two adjacent parabolas intersect as measured from 0.

One can apply a similar line of reasoning to compute the charge dispersion of higher excited states. I won't lay out the details, but a key difference is that the diagonal entries for each of the relevant subspaces can no longer be made equal (as was the case for $H_{01}(n_g=0.5)$. Because of this, the energy splittings are reduced to small shifts $\sim E_J^2/E_C$, hence the visible reduction shown in Fig. (a). This is important, as we can now argue from a graphical standpoint why the charge dispersion increases for higher excited states: the splitting size decreases and
$$
\frac{d}{d n_g} \bigg((n-n_g)^2 \bigg)
$$
increases with respect to the *fixed* values of $n$ that define the relevent energy level.

Now let's consider case (ii): the transmon. Owing to the energy scales, it makes a lot more sense to consider this system in the phase basis, but for this particular question we can stick with the $|n\rangle$'s. Basically the transmon is a harmonic oscillator, and we know that for a harmonic oscillator, the characteristic spread in charge (or flux) will increase with higher excited states. This is the essence of Fig. 6 from the Koch paper, included below for completeness:
[image]

The projection of this spread onto the number basis shows that higher excited states of the transmon will require mores states from the number basis for a faithful representation, and each of these states has an energy cost $4E_C (n-n_g)^2$ associated with it. From our analysis of case (i), it should be clear that the energy cost will increase with increasing $n$.

Let me know if any of this was unclear or if you have follow up questions based on what I wrote. Charge qubits are definitely a thing of the past, but check out [Schuster's thesis](https://rsl.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/RSL_Theses/SchusterThesis.pdf) for some more details on those. For experiments on charge sensitive transmons, I recommend [arXiv:1212.5459](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5459),    [arXiv:1905.13712](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.13712), and [arXiv:1803.00476](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00476).

Comment: Very clear, thank you! The only comment I would have is that this approach (regarding the derivative) is of a somewhat mathematical nature. I would also be interested in a physical interpretation that involves, say, the barrier given by the Josephson potential. In Koch's seminal paper he finds that the dispersion exponentially suppresses in $E_J/E_C$, which can be interpreted as tunneling through a barrier of a particle with mass set by $E_C$ in the WKB sense. And interestingly, this rate is almost exactly identical to the phase slip rate, see eq 7 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0207277.pdf

Comment: This to me implies a connection between phase slips and charge dispersion , which makes sense from a conjugate variable perspective. Less phase slips means less phase fluctuations, more charge fluctuations, and thus less charge dispersion, as it is a measure of charge localization and Coulomb blockade oscillations. Would the higher levels then just have less charge dispersion because they live higher in the potential well, and thus have an easier time tunneling through the barrier?

Comment: I agree that the probability of a phase slips decreases with decreasing $\Delta \phi$, but I disagree that small $\Delta \phi \implies$ large $\Delta Q$. It seems to me that you are assuming $\Delta \phi \Delta Q = \hbar/2$, but the energy eigenstates of the transmon are not mininum uncertainty states.

Comment: Well, if $\Delta \phi$ becomes small enough, then you do have to make $\Delta Q$ large at some point, right? But you are probably correct that I am making statements that are too general. Do you have a better explanation of why the phase slip amplitude and the dispersion seem to be so intimately connected?

Comment: I believe it come from Bloch's theorem. Basically, you have a periodic potential ($U(\phi) = U(\phi + 2\pi)$), and in a tight-binding treatment of the problem, the true wavefunction is (more or less) a superposition of wavefunctions localized at $\phi = 0, \pm 2\pi, \pm 4 \pi, \ldots$. This wavefunction gives rise to a Bloch band, where the amount of 'band bending' will depend on how much adjacent wavefunctions overlap (less overlap $\implies$ less bending). But less overlap, means more barrier, and more barrier means less phase slips (think WKB). I think the argument goes something like that.